# BigQuery View to Update Table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have a logging table which consists of raw data that require processing, which sometimes will require to set a destination table to avoid resource error.

Currently I am using a BigQuery View to process and persist the result in another BigQuery table, with Scheduled Query set to overwrite the table.

As the volume of data grows, I find that the cost is getting more expensive, how do I construct it in a more efficient/better practice in order to save cost?

My current BigQuery View script logic is like this:

```
with latest_timestamp as(
select max(timestamp) latest from persist_table
),

select col1, col2, col3 from logging_table where timestamp >= (select latest from latest_timestamp)
union all
select * from persist_table where timestamp < (select latest from latest_timestamp)
```

I have to use the timestamp as timestamp is the partition column, and to avoid duplicate/missing data in the result.
Not sure if there is any other better way to do this so I will be open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps should make you insert only the new lines, avoid you to read and insert the entire table every time. Have in mind that Bigquery charges you based on the bytes read. So using partitioning and not having to read the entire table to reinsert it every time you save costs.

- Ensure all tables are partitioned by the timestamp if its not done already (logging_table and persist_table): *Its reduces a lot the data needed to be read*;
- Change your schedule query to the following:

```sql
with latest_timestamp as(
select max(timestamp) latest from persist_table
)

select col1, col2, col3  from logging_table where timestamp > (select latest from latest_timestamp)
union all
(select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3 from 
(select col1, col2, col3  from logging_table where timestamp = (select latest from latest_timestamp)) t1
left join 
(select * from persist_table where timestamp = (select latest from latest_timestamp)) t2
on
(t1.col1=t2.col1 and t1.col2=t2.col2 and t1.col3=t2.col3)
where
t2.col1 is null)
```

**AND**

- Change the `Overwrite` to `Append to table`:

[image]

Comment: It works but the processing is still the same as the original query.
I am using left join instead of right join though, in order to get all the records from logging_table which have the same timestamp but yet to be processed into the persist_table.

Comment: 1. you are correct, changed to left. 2. If the processing is the same, you made a mistake on the partitions, or you are not using it.  by **definition**, query the amount of data using partitions filters and the entire table must be different. Please read all the details on the answer.  *"Ensure all tables are partitioned by the timestamp"*

Comment: I did cross-check all the steps and confirmed both tables are partitioned with timestamp. I understand the logic here, by right it should be lesser when we are only selecting the data >= timestamp instead of the original < timestamp. But the UI processing byte is the same as compared to the original script.

Comment: In anyway I recommend you to keep with this approach, cause also the you of append you reduce the ingestion data costs

Comment: Yes this approach is definitely better, I will accept this as the answer, thank you.